# Consider preallocating for speed

Tags: matlab, memory-management

I was doing the following

```
for i = 1:m,
    index = 0;
    for j = 1:n,
        index = index+values(i,j)*2^(j-1);
        if (j==1)
            symbol_chip = chip_values(index+1,:);
        else
            symbol_chip = [symbol_chip chip_values(index+1,:)];
        end
    end
end
```

it tells me the following:

> `symbol_chip` might be growing inside the loop. Consider preallocating for speed.

Any ideas?

Comment: To avoid repetition, in a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548116/matrix-of-unknown-length-in-matlab/1549094#1549094 , I showed a way that improves performance by pre-allocating memory while still being efficient in terms of space by adding more memory space when needed

Comment: Have you ever tried Matlab Help??? Just press F1 in any Matlab Window, type 'preallocation' in search edit feld and press ENTER. You will get exactly what you need!!!

Comment: Just a comment: it is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Each time you go around, your `elseif` block is resizing `symbol_chip`, which is expensive. Instead, rewrite your code so that you have (say) `symbol_chip = zeros(max_size, 1);` before the loop. Then, change the contents but not the size of `symbol_chip`.

You'll need to slightly change your approach, but it will be much faster if you do. If you're not annoyed by the current speed, don't change anything!

Comment: sorry i corrected it should read else not elseif

Comment: let's say before the outer for loop i put the 

symbol_chip = zeros(m*32,1);

then how would i change my if-else statement?

Answer (score 2):

M-Lint will throw this warning if you have a variable that grows inside a loop without being preallocated.  You can remove this error by pre-allocating the collection variable.

For instance, if you knew that the variable symbol_chip would have at most i*j elements, you could preallocate it with the statement:

```
symbol_chip = zeros(i*j);
```

However, for most applications preallocation will only have a negligible effect on algorithm performance.  I would only worry about it if you are dealing with very large data sets.

Comment: zeros(i*j) will create a 2D array with i*j rows and i*j columns. To fix this use zeros(i*j,1)