# How to remove pre-allocation warning in this situation

Tags: matlab, allocation

When plotting a set of figures using a for loop, for example:

```
for ei=1:length(E),
  hnds(ei) = plot(1:nP, avgR(ei,:), [clrStr(ei),'-'] ); 
end
```

There is a (the famous) warning in the code for the **hnds(ei)** variable:

> The variable hnds(ei) appears to change size on every loop iteration.
>   Consider pre-allocating for speed.

But when I try to pre-allocate the variable:

```
hnds = zeros(1,length(E));
```

there is another warning for this new line and in the details for pre-allocation it says:

> Suggested Action:  Avoid preallocating memory to a variable assigned to
>   the output of another function.

Is there any way to remove this warning, or should just ignore it?

Comment: What is your Matlab version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [matlab - consider preallocating for speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151636/matlab-consider-preallocating-for-speed)

Comment: version : 2013a & 2013b

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate - after all NKN tried pre-allocating the variable, only to get another warning that advised against the pre-allocation he had chosen.

Comment: **Note** that the answers below might be useful, but the cause of this second warning is that the preallocation is in the wrong location. Don't preallocate the output to a function, preallocate inside your function, just outside the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try iterate in reverse order to avoid the warning:

```
for ei=length(E):-1:1,
    hnds(ei) = plot(1:nP, avgR(ei,:), [clrStr(ei),'-'] ); 
end
```

In this case you do not need to pre-allocate (i.e., no `hnds = zeros(1,length(E));`).

By iterating in reverse order, the array size `hnds` is determined in the **first** iteration and stays fixed throughout the iterations.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21023172/1714410) for more information.

Answer (score 9):

Just put special `%#ok` comment at the end of the line and it will disable all warnings associated with this line:

```
hnds = zeros(1,length(E)); %#ok
```

You can also use special `%#ok<specific1, ...>` comment to disable only very specific warnings but not other ones. Check this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/check-code-for-errors-and-warnings.html#brqxeeu-169) for furhter details.

Comment: nice trick I did not know that! It's been a while haha thanks for that.

Comment: Bless you for sharing this. This is perfect for so many things!

Answer (score 3):

You can deactivate it in **Preferences**:

[image]

(Matlab 2013b)

I think it is not possible to suppress this certain warning in this certain loop of a single script, just global.
It's different for warnings which are displayed in the command window, they can be [suppressed individually](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/suppress-warnings.html).

**Edit: [I was wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23142479/2605073)**