# MATLAB efficient dynamically expanding primitive

Tags: data-structures, matlab

Just wondering if MATLAB has an efficient dynamically expanding primitive, something akin to Java Collections? I realise that the Java API is always an option, but it can be a complete pain to use. Of course something like the ArrayList would be simple to implement, but I was specifically wondering about built-in data structures.

Thanks very much.

Comment: this has been discussed before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1548116/97160 (also make sure to look at the linked questions on the side)

Answer (score 1):

[Map Containers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brqqo5e-1.html) should fit your criteria of built-in data structure.

*Java Collections Framework* might not be best as example for 'expanding primitive'. It is a framework implemented based on the Java language. Even in Java, 'primitive data types' are breaking pure object orientation.