# How to concatenate all the variables of two different matlab files?

Tags: matlab, concatenation

I have two mat files with identical list of variables.

In file1.mat

```
*Variables*       *Value*       *Type*       

Time              [100X1]       double

Force             [100x1]       double
```

In file2.mat

```
*Variables*      *Value*       *Type*       

Time_1           [90X1]        double

Force_1          [90x1]        double
```

I would like to vertically concatenate these two files. The suffix `_1` added to the file2 changes to `_2` or `_32` etc.

How can I refer the variables  and concatenate them in a loop so I don't have to open the file every time and enter the variable names in `vertcat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two nice properties of the `load` command for this task. Firstly, `load` with an output argument creates a structure with field names equal to the variable names, which means that you can load data without having to know ahead of time what the variables were named. Secondly, the fields are assigned in alphabetical order, which means that `force` will always be the first field, and `time` the second field.

Combining these properties, you can do the following:

```
%# get a listing of all save files
fileList = dir('file*');
nFiles = length(fileList);

loadedData = cell(nFiles,2); %# for storing {force,time}

%# loop through files and write results into loadedData
for iFile = 1:nFiles
    tmp = load(fileList{iFile});
    loadedData(iFile,:) = struct2cell(tmp)';
end

%# catenate
time = cat(1,loadedData(:,2));
force = cat(1,loadedData(:,1));
```

Note that if your files are called `file1`...`file10`, instead of `file001`...`file010`, the alphabetical ordering you get from using the `dir` command may not be ideal. In that case, you may have to extract the number  at the end of the file name and re-order the list.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following code snippet help to solve your problem?

```
Time_1 = [1; 2];
Time_2 = [2; 3];
Time_3 = 4;
All = [];
for i = 1:3
    CurTime = eval(horzcat('Time_', num2str(i)));
    All = [All; CurTime];
end
```

Essentially what is happening is I'm looping over the suffixes of `Time_1`, `Time_2`, and `Time_3`. For each iteration, I obtain the pertinent `Time_x` variable by manually building the name of the variable in a string, and then allocating it to `CurTime` using the `eval` function. Then simply perform the desired concatenation using `CurTime`

Of course, this code is not very efficient as `All` is growing within the loop. If you know the size of `All` beforehand, then you can pre-allocate it. If the size is unknown before the fact, you can implement the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548116/matrix-of-unknown-length-in-matlab) (or else just pre-allocate it as being arbitrarily large and then cut it down to size once the loop is complete).

Let me know if I've misunderstood the problem you're having and I'll try and come up with something more helpful.

Also, some people think `eval` is evil. Certainly if your code contains 10 different calls to `eval` then you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The Problem I am running into is, I have 100+ variables and I would like to keep the variable names of the first file (i.e variable without the suffix) without introducing a new variable.

Comment: @Prasanna: then just use `Time = [Time; CurTime];`

Comment: @Prasanna You can keep the workspace slim by reading each file within the loop, applying the `eval` command as I have above, and then clear the variable that was loaded using something like `eval(['clear ', horzcat('Time_', num2str(i)]);`. However, this involves another use of `eval`. A much neater solution is the one suggested by Jonas (+1 to you sir). I would suggest you accept that answer and take the time to learn to use structures as suggested in that answer.

Comment: Its a good start. Am investigating dynamic field names to use with large number of unknown variables. thanks