# How can I create an expandable array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

How can I create an expandable array in Matlab?

I can create a fixed length array with `myArray = zeros(1,2);` But I need one that I can keep pushing new elements onto the list. How should I run the command to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign the value to the item.

```
myArray = zeros(1,2);
myArray(1,3)=3; % item assignment
```

myArray will be of dimension (1,3) now.

Comment: Will the values in myArray remain when I reassign its dimension?

Comment: Yes. Basically, you're expanding the array by assigning a value at an item location. You can check out basics http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB arrays/matrices are dynamic by construction. `myArray = [];` will create a dynamic array. From there on you can assign and extend (by appending or concatenation). Some examples:

```
myArray = zeros(1,2);
myArray(:,end+1) = 1;
myArray(end+1,:) = ones(1,3);
myArray = [myArray 2*myArray];
```

An interesting analysis on the efficiency of different array resizing options in MATLAB, if pre-allocation is not an option, can be found here: [Array resizing performance](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/array-resizing-performance).

You can also check this SO post: [Matrix of unknown length in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548116/matrix-of-unknown-length-in-matlab).