# MATLAB : Appending to pre-allocated matrix

Tags: matlab, memory-management

I have some MATLAB code with mxn matrix.
Initially, I put first row in it and then the code runs through a for loop which appends remaining m-1 rows one by one; one for each iteration of the loop.
As expected, MATLAB recommends me to pre-allocate the matrix because it is expanding with every iteration of loop.
So, if I pre-allocate zeros in all m rows, MATLAB most probably will append rows after the m rows(starting from m+1 for 1st appended row) because m rows are already filled(even though with zeros!)
Is there any way of pre-allocating matrix in this scenario for improving speed?

Comment: downvoters care to explain the reason? Don't be rude guys. I am trying to learn MATLAB here and this is my second MATLAB program..
I could not find other relevant question on SO..

Comment: Didn't downvote, personally, but your question is not clear.  It would be vastly improved by including a snippet of your code, and some idea of what your final matrix should be (or a reduced example if your final matrix is large).

Comment: @nkjt:Is it clear now?

Comment: What I was saying was you should show your code (just the loop). You're probably doing something you shouldn't (as chappjc suggested, appending rows with `A = [A; rowVec];` onto a pre-allocated matrix, perhaps).

Comment: @nkjt:that's exactly what I was doing....so foolish of me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pre-allocate a MATLAB array without also changing it's size, at least not manually.  However, MATLAB has improved automatic array growth performance a lot in recent versions, so you might not see a huge performance hit.  Still, best practice would be to pre-allocate your array with `zeros` and index the rows with `A(i,:) = rowVec;` instead of appending a row (`A = [A; rowVec];`).

### Pre-allocation

If you are determined to squeeze every bit of performance out of MATLAB, Yair Altman has a couple of excellent articles on the topic of memory pre-allocation:

- [Preallocation performance](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance/)
- [Preallocation performance and multithreading](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/allocation-performance-take-2/)

### Automatic Array Growth Optimization

If you really want to use dynamic array resizing by growing along a dimension, there are ways to do it right.  See this this [MathWorks blog post by Steve Eddins](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/05/20/more-about-automatic-array-growth-improvements-in-matlab-r2011a/).  The most important thing to note is that you should **grow along the last dimension for best performance**. (i.e. add columns in your case).  Yair also discusses dynamic array resizing in [another post on his blog](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/array-resizing-performance/).

Also, there are ways of allocating an array without initializing using some hairy MEX API acrobatics, but that's it.

Comment: I think the key point here to answer @tumchaaditya's question is that once you pre-allocate your matrix, you need to write your output row to the correct row of the (initially zero) matrix, rather than keep appending rows.

Comment: @SchighSchagh: Right.  Use `A(i,:) = rowVec;` instead of `A = [A; rowVec];` (or whatever tumchaaditya was doing).