# save matrix value which create in each loop save in common matrix ,each loop matrix has same row size but column is ow

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

```
a=18;
b=22;
for i=1:10
r1 = randi([18 22],1,1)
name= (b-a).*rand(r1,2) + a
end
```

now save this all **name value matrix** in **result matrix** of all genrated value
in each loop row size not fix but coiumn is 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix of unknown length in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548116/matrix-of-unknown-length-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

preallocate the maximum sized matrix and remove redundant rows at the end:

```
a = 18;
b = 22;
% number of iterations
n = 10;
% maximum number of rows
maxRows = b*n;
% preallocating matrix
nameMat = zeros(maxRows,2);
currentRow = 0;
for i = 1:n
    r1 = randi([18 22],1,1);
    name = (b-a).*rand(r1,2) + a;
    nameRows = size(name,1);
    nameMat((1:nameRows) + currentRow,:) = name;
    currentRow = currentRow + nameRows; 
end
% remove redundant rows
nameMat(currentRow+1:end,:) = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with one line code; actually in each iteration of the loop
you:

- generate an `integer` random number `r1` (e. g. `20`)
- it is then used to generate `r1` `double` random number that are multiplied by `(b-a)`
  and then added to `a`
- these random numbers are not affected by the ones generated in a previos iteration
- `a` and `b` are constant so do not change in the loop

At the end of your loop you the number of row will be the `sum` of the 
`integer` random number, so you can directly generate the `10` integer random numbers in the evaluation of `name` and `sum` them to create the desired set `name` values:

```
a=18;
b=22;
n_iter=10;

name=(b-a).*rand(sum(randi([18 22],n_iter,1)),2) + a
```

Hope this helps,

Qapla'