# Matlab: Array growing inside a loop - so what?

Tags: performance, matlab, memory-management

I have this code (reading images into a huge matrix)

```
allImages = [];
for ii = 1 : n
    img = imread( fileNames{ii} );
    img = imresize( rgb2gray(img), [100 100] );
    allImages = cat(3, allImages, img ); % append image to huge matrix
end
```

Matlab points me to the last line in the loop warning me that `allIamges` grows inside the loop.

So what's the big deal here?

Comment: @EitanT missed that. I just flagged my answer asking it to be moved to that question. Thanks for spotting the duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a big deal.

In term of correctness - the code does what is expected. The issue here is performance.

#### What happens behind the scenes?

When a new image is appended to `allImages`, Matlab has to find a **contiguous** region of memory (i.e. all in one chunk) for the resized `allImages`. This usually entails a new memory allocation for the resized `allImages`, copying of old data and de-allocation of the old `allImages`.
These re-allocation + copy operations that occur behind the scene (probably at each iteration!) can be very time consuming.

---

#### What can be done?

**1. Pre-allocate**: If you know the number of images and the final size of `allImages`, reserve this space beforehand:

```
allImages = zeros( 100, 100, n ); % pre-allocate, fill with zeros.
for ii = 1 : n
    % ...
    allImages(:,:, ii ) = img; % write into pre-allocated array
end
```

**2. What if I don't know `n` beforehand?**: There are several questions already dealing with this issue. For example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1549094/1714410).

Comment: +1, however, [R2011a has improved the situation](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/05/20/more-about-automatic-array-growth-improvements-in-matlab-r2011a/) quite substantially.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis It would have driven me crazy...

Comment: woodchips has also written a nice post about this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/783137/97160